# Is there a relationship between on which of devices was created stream and on which device will executed code?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

If I use this code, then will be it executed on device 0 or 1?

```
cudaSetDevice(0);       // switch to device 0
cudaStream_t stream1;
cudaStreamCreate(&stream1); // created on device 0
cudaSetDevice(1);       // switch to device 1
kernel_function<<<10, 1024, 0, stream1>>>();    // executed on device 0 or 1?
```

Is there a relationship between on which of devices was created stream and on which device will executed code?

Comment: That code snippet would produce a runtime error because you are using stream1 in a different context/device from the one it was created in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading the following example from the [CUDA webinar on using multiple GPUs](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/cuda_webinars_multi_gpu.pdf) correctly, it is an error to execute with a stream that is not on the currently selected device.

**Example 2**

```
cudaStream_t streamA, streamB;
cudaEvent_t eventA, eventB;
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaStreamCreate(&streamA); // streamA and eventA belong to device-0
cudaEventCreaet(&eventA);
cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaStreamCreate(&streamB); // streamB and eventB belong to device-1
cudaEventCreate (&eventB);
kernel<<<...,  streamA>>>(...);
cudaEventRecord(eventB, streamB);
cudaEventSynchronize( eventB);
```

**ERROR:**

- device-1 is current
- streamA belongs to device-0